# How To Remove or Hide Column in Jspdf AutoTable While using Material Table

Tags: angular, angular-material, jspdf, jspdf-autotable

I Have an angular material table that I want to convert to PDF Excluding The Last Column on the image below with jsPDF autoTable
https://i.stack.imgur.com/FoaAy.png,
in component where I'm downloading the pdf the code is:

> downloadingPDF: boolean = false

> @Input() employees!: Employee[]; < datasource

`displayedColumns = ['id','name', .... ,'details'];`

```
  downloadPdf() {
this.downloadingPDF = true;
let doc = new jsPDF();
autoTable(doc, { html: '#table', theme: 'grid' });
doc.save('test.pdf')  };
```

this is my Html

```
 <button mat-raised-button color="primary" (click)="downloadPdf()" style="float: right;">
  {{ "Download PDF" | translate }}
</button>
```

```
<table id="table" mat-table matTableExporter [dataSource]="employees" class="mat-elevation-z8" #exporter="matTableExporter" [hiddenColumns]="[8]">
<!-- ID Column -->
<ng-container matColumnDef="id">
  <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>ID</th>
  <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let employee">{{ employee.id }}</td>
</ng-container>

 <!-- DETAILS COLUMN -->
<ng-container matColumnDef="details" *ngIf="!downloadingPDF">
  <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>{{ "Details" | translate }}</th>
  <td
    mat-cell
    *matCellDef="let employee"
    routerLink="detail/{{ employee.id }}"
  >
  <button mat-raised-button color="primary">
    {{ "Details" | translate }}
  </button>
  </td>
</ng-container>
 <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns; sticky: true"></tr>
<tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns"></tr>
</table>
```

I have tried doing it with a boolean value but I couldn't get it to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 downloadPdf() {
this.downloadingPDF = true;
let doc = new jsPDF();
autoTable(doc, { html: '#table', theme: 'grid' });
doc.save('test.pdf')  }
```

the solution was:

```
downloadPdf() {
    this.downloadingPDF = true;
    let doc = new jsPDF();
    autoTable(
      doc, 
      { 
        html: '#table',
         theme: 'grid', 
         columns: 
         [
          {header: 'Id', dataKey: 'id'},
          {header: 'Name', dataKey: 'name'},
          {header: 'Email', dataKey: 'email'},
          {header: 'City', dataKey: 'city'},
          {header: 'Company', dataKey: 'companyName'},
          {header: 'Department', dataKey: 'Department'},
          {header: 'Position', dataKey: 'position'},
          {header: 'Salary', dataKey: 'salary'},
        ],
        
        });
    doc.save('test.pdf');
 
  }
```

It was a very simple solution even tought it's not the best looking it did the job.

Comment: I only needed to escape the last column I'm not sure this will work for you if you need to remove something from the middle of the array